# How to fix inverted color on one thunderbolt monitor with maximum resolution set?

Tags: macos, display, macbook-pro

I have two monitors. All of the sudden my second monitor has switched blue for red when it is at the full resolution 2560x1600. However, white is not black, so it isn't totally inverted.

If I use the same monitor on a different thunderbolt port at the full resolution this problem doesn't happen.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to have fixed it:

```
sudo mv /Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver.plist ~/Desktop/
sudo mv /Users/kbrandt/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.windowserver.CDE1EF8A-5D17-5A4E-AFB8-C4D1E19616DD.plist ~/
```

Followed by a reboot. I expect there may be a more targeted way to fix this, but this worked for now.

If you can forgive a little rant, I also have to `killall Dock` to get the wallpaper on the second monitor, and use SwitchResX to get the monitor to display the proper resolution. In short, it seems OS X sucks with multiple monitors (at least with non-apple displays).

Comment: I've never had a bad experience running multiple monitors, so I'd expect those to be driver problems with the new MacBook rather than OS X per se. You should definitely send Apple feedback on these.

Comment: @StevenFisher: This actually my first mac, happen to have a link for the proper channel to send them this feedback?

Comment: Probably here: http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html

Comment: I said probably because if you're VERY technical, there's also Apple's developer bug report system. But you probably want the link I said. :)